# RxJS: combine multiple observables dynamically over time

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, recursion, rxjs

My problem is recursive, and I don't know when my Observable `complete()` in a recursive function.

Basically, I have function is scrapping a website with a pagination functionality and it's returning an Observable that pushes the "parsed" items found on each page with the `.next(data)` method, and doing that recursively until we find ourselves on the last page and then we triggering the `.complete()` method of our Subject.

I'm using the `concat(Observable)` method to concatenate the new Observable with the current Observable recursively but it doesn't seem to work, when I subscribe to my observable I only get the items of the first page, which make me guess that the `concat()` method is not working for my case.

Here is a simplified version of my function code.

```

```
crawlList(url) {
    let obsSubject = new Subject();
    request(url, function (err, response, body) {
        //check if everything is alright...
        //parsing data...
        obsSubject.next(parsedData);
        //now we check if we can still paginate (we are not in the last page)
        //if so, we concat our observable with the new observable recursivly
        obsSubject.concat(crawList(url))
        //else ,(we are in the last page
        obsSubject.complete();
    });
    return obsSubject;
}
```

```

Comment: `concat` doesn't modify the Observable/Subject, it returns a new one. Try `obsSubject = obsSubject.concat(crawList(url));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general avoid using `Subject`s unless you are *certain* you can't do it with operators.

In this case I would expect that `expand` would work here. Where the result of the previous stream is fed back into the operator so that it can be recursively executed.

Something like:

```
// Convert the callback into an Observable
const rxRequest = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(
  request,
  (response, body) => ({response, body})
);    

// Feed the initial data set, by default we should continue
Observable.of({url: baseUrl, shouldContinue: true})
  .expand(({url, shouldContinue}) => {
    // Return an empty stream to cancel the Observable
    // note this is from the *previous* iteration
    if (!shouldContinue)
      return Rx.Observable.empty();

    // This is how we call the newly created method
    return rxRequest(url)
      .map(({response, body}) => 
        // Parse data
        // Check if you should continue or not
        // We still need to emit this data so we can't cancel until the next
        // go-around
        ({url: newUrl, data: parsedData, shouldContinue})
      );
  })
  // Downstream only cares about the data part
  .pluck('data')
```